# how to hide one layer with adobe javascript when layers added with PyPDF2

Tags: javascript, python, pdf, adobe

I want to add two layers in pdf with PyPDF2. The top layer is a blank layer which block the whole page. The other added layer is watermark.

In javascript added with addJS(), I want to hide the top layer with some condition, which means I want to show the original pdf with watermark, but not the top layer. But when i read adobe javascript, i found there were two problems:

1) I know adobe javascript can add layer and hide it, but i'm not sure if I add a layer with PyPDF2, adobe javascript can hide it.

2) In adobe javascript, it can hide layer with name. But I add layer with PyPDF2, I didn't see how I can add a layer with name.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing layers and layers.

The concept of layers you're talking about (the things you can show and hide with Adobe Javascript) are technically referred to as "Optional Content". You may also come across the terms OCG (Optional Content Group), OCCD (Optional Content Configuration Dictionary) or OCMD (Optional Content Membership Dictionary).

As far as I can see PyPDF2 doesn't support this. Have a look at this (still open) ticket for example: https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/92.

So when PyPDF2 talks about adding a layer on top of a PDF (or layering two PDFs together), they are simply talking about taking the content of one PDF file and adding it on top of another PDF. This will merge the content objects of the two PDF files, but without inserting any Optional Content information.

Hence the type of layers you are talking about with PyPDF2 cannot be turned on or off with Adobe Javascript because they are not "Optional Content" layers.

In order to do what you want you need to find a library or tool that can add a PDF on top of another PDF using the Optional Content system.

Comment: Yeah. i had no experience to work on pdf. This is what I guessed. I think you already gave me a really good answer about my question. It proved that my thought cannot work. I'm going to create another further question, please take a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: Here is my further question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639933/how-to-set-expiry-date-on-pdf-open-with-preview-on-mac